# Unity Animation Transition Weird bug

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I'm trying to make it so the character will go from being idle to picking something(ive tried doing it myself with animation rigging but it didn't work for some reason) and for some reason whenever the transition is happening instead of doing the animation my character just glitches to the ground like that(I got all the animations from mixamo)

[image: as you can see he's just bending like that and does not play the animation]

Comment: set animations and your model to Humanoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Rig section change the type from Generic to Humanoid.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should make sure that the animations and your avatar are retargeted to humanoid. A helpful article can be found in the Unity Manuals.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Retargeting.html

> One of the most powerful features of Mecanim is retargeting of humanoid animations
> . This means that with relative ease, you can apply the same set of animations to various character models. Retargeting is only possible for humanoid models, where an Avatar
> has been configured, because this gives us a correspondence between the models’ bone structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have your character as a kinematic, do it, maybe it fix your problem